# How to take samples of 300V signal

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics

I want to digitize (convert from analog to digital) a signal that can vary from -300 volts to +300 volts. Can anybody suggest how to handle this high voltage signal?

Comment: Resistor divider with high resolution ADC might be a choice?

Comment: Can i use ADC IC at such high voltage.

Comment: No, you use resistor divider to bring the voltage down to a safe level and sample that. Say, you use 300K and 3K resistors, you'd see around -3 to +3 signal (scaling down 100 times).

Comment: But i want to use this circuit to measure voltages in a circuit..i.e., i want to use this somewhat like a multimeter. Does'nt use of a resistor at the input going to alter current in a circuit in which i want to measure the voltage.

Comment: You should add to your question to clarify your intended usage and what you're trying to measure that's outputting +/-300V

Comment: Let us assume that there is a  circuit in which there is a voltage drop of some 240v across some resistor in that circuit. Now i want to digitize voltage drop across that resistor. How do i do that.

Comment: If you can estimate the maximum resistance, then you could pick the resistor in range of 10 times greater than that so the loading effect can be minimized.

Comment: 1mA does'nt affect much, But i think it is better to have a opamp in voltage follower configuration prior to resistor devider circuit. Having opamp may reduce the drawn current to less than 1mA

Comment: To know whether you need to buffer the signal, we need to know how much current leakage you can accept in the measurement circuit, and how fast a change in voltage you need to be able to measure (the bandwidth of the measurement). If the signal is an AC signal, or you don't need to measure the DC component, you could also consider using a transformer to step down to easier-to-work-with voltage levels.

Comment: "I want to use it like a multimeter" - well, there's a _clue_ there, multimeters are already digitising these voltages with very little loading.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Pyxzure's comment, the simplest solution is really just using resistors, in a voltage divider configuration:

[image]

Find how much current the circuit(s) you want to measure need, divide it by a factor (say 10 or 20) and that current is almost certainly negligible and won't affect your circuit in any significant way. Call this small current *i*. Then, the resistor values can be easily calculated with (assuming you want a max of 3V):

R2 = 3/i

R1 = 300/i - R2

You can make the resistor divider draw as little current as you wish, just use bigger resistors, lowering the *i* value.

Also make sure that the power rating for the resistors is compatible. If you are using 1/4W resistors, for instance, make sure that P2 and P1 are both less than 0.25, where:

P2 = R2*i^2

P1 = R1*i^2

(Just checking P1 is enough)

If you really really want to , then there are suitable power Op-amps that you can use in a voltage follower configuration (such as digikey PN: 598-1917-ND), but that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Pyxzure has the right answer in the comments above.  When you make a voltage divider you need to choose resistors large enough so that their addition won't appreciably change the current flow in the actual circuit.  You can then use a normal ADC (or similar) to read off the reduced voltage: V_div = V_in * R_small / (R_large + R_Small).  This is really no different from using a multimeter -- multimeters have some large but finite internal resistance.